# how can I make webkit's developer console behave more like firebug?

Tags: safari, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

In firebug, if I do something like:

$('a');

I will see something like:

[a.foo, a#bar]

...

If I do the same thing in chrome or safari, I will see:

Object

with a little disclosure triangle by it that I have to click to identify what it is...  Is there a way to make the webkit tools output more useful data and not require me to click to expand details?

Comment: if I run `$("a:first")` on this page within chrome I'll get
`[
<a class=​"genu" onclick=​"StackExchange.ready(function()​{genuwine.click()​;​}​)​;​return false;​">​Stack Exchange​</a>​
]`

Answer (score 1):

It’s slightly better in the current [Chrome Canary](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs):

[image: Console jQuery object]